# ggplot legend does not appear

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

My code for the plot is the following

```
ggplot(NULL, aes(V2, V1)) + 
  geom_line(data = df1, colour = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = df2, colour = "green") +
  geom_line(data = df3, colour = "purple") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom") +
```

df1, df2, and df3 have the same following structure

```
V2 V1
1  1.4
2  1.5
3  1.9
4  4.5
5  6.7
6  7.8
7  8.1
8  8.2
9  8.3
10 8.9
```

The output does not show the legend, but I need to differentiate between the lines on the plot.

[image: I add the picture of the plot output I receive]. I need just to have the legend here.

Comment: Does df1, df2, df3 has the same V2 column ? Can you provide an example of the structure of df2 and df3 ? maybe you can join them in order to plot them with a single `geom_line`

Comment: df1, df2, df3 have the same V2 column. I have added in the question the plot I receive in the output. I need 3 different lines, not one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it would be helpful if you get the data into one dataframe, then plot the data with one `geom_line` instead of multiple.

```
library(ggplot2)

dplyr::bind_rows(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3, .id = "id") %>%
  ggplot() +  aes(V2, V1, color = id) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(V2 = 1:10, V1 = c(1.4, 1.5, 1.9, 4.5, 6.7, 7.8, 
8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

df2 <- structure(list(V2 = 1:10, V1 = c(1.43390152077191, 2.30610947613604, 
2.23775280718692, 5.41628585802391, 7.05710641788319, 8.77536501311697, 
8.48437852263451, 8.68867353517562, 8.7907762312796, 8.91225462416187
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

df3 <- structure(list(V2 = 1:10, V1 = c(2.04147320063785, 2.01257497165352, 
2.22035211822949, 5.08143315766938, 7.31734440829605, 8.23827453767881, 
8.27036898061633, 8.91508049662225, 9.04778654868715, 9.74391470812261
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: in your example, the lines on the plot intersect sometimes. Is it possible to find out the coordinates of intersection?

Comment: @YuliiaZhaha those intersections are not actually points in the dataframes but it is when they cross each other. Maybe it is possible to find them but it is worth asking it as a new question separately.

Comment: Thank you! I've used your code example from above. If you have some thoughts on the question, it is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59613207/r-coordinates-of-lines-intersections-in-a-plot